# Understanding the SWAP step of PAM K-medoids

Tags: clustering, algorithms, k-medoids

In what I believe is the [original PAM paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/243777819_Clustering_by_Means_of_Medoids), the swap step is described like so:

> *"This is done by considering all pairs of objects (i, h) for which object i has been selected and object h has not. It is determined what
> effect is obtained when a swap is carried out; i.e. when object i is
> no longer selected as a representative object but object h is."*

So this is interesting to me for a couple of reasons. Firstly, the BUILD step as I understand it iteratively selects the "representative objects" as medoids that reduce the overall dissimilarity. For the first iteration, the object selected reduces dissimilarity from it to all other objects. The second medoid selected will consider the average dissimilarity between it and its closest non-medoids PLUS the average dissimilarity between the first centroid and its closest non-medoids. **This seems very expensive**.

The second point of interest is that in combination BUILD + SWAP seems deterministic. BUILD is "greedy", which I take to mean finding the locally best solution every time starting with the first medoid which will always be the "center" of the data. And if the data isn't changing, then BUILD is deterministic. Then, for every initial medoid, every possible swap is considered, this seems to be an exhaustive search.

But [this similar discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/254925/is-partitioning-around-medoids-pam-deterministic) says that it is not deterministic (but almost) because of the case of ties. However, the original paper says that ties are broken on a first-come-first-serve basis. That makes things seem completely deterministic to me. Secondly, the answer states that the swap step is NOT exhaustive. However, the paper indeed says every (i, h) is considered.

So all of this leads to the question, **How is the swap step not exhaustive and how is the algorithm not deterministic?**

And a second, I think related question if you will allow it: **What is the difference between *"only computing the change in cost"* vs *"recomputing the entire cost function"* referenced in the [K-medoids wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids)?** In order to know the "new" cost of a swap you have to measure the effect on the whole, so it seems necessary to recompute the entire cost function.